# Generate pedigree tree YII2

Tags: yii2

I am trying to generate pedigree
my DB schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `Pedigrees` ( 
`pedigrees_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`horse_name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`sire_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`dam_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`pedigrees_id`),
and other info data
```

Generete GII CRUD for controller model and index.php and viev.php

get info for SIRE and DAM to viev.php

Model Pedigrees:

```
public function getParentsir()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Pedigrees::className(), ['pedigrees_id' => 'sire_id']);
    }
    public function getParentdam()
    {
       return $this->hasOne(Pedigrees::className(), ['pedigrees_id' => 'dam_id']);
    }
```

and for viev.php use html + php ()

```
<?php if ($model->parentdam->parentdam->parentdam->parentdam) {
        echo Html::a(Html::encode($model->parentdam->parentdam->parentdam->parentdam->name));
    }else{
        echo "<tr><td><li>none</li></td></tr>";
  }?>
```

and table example:

```
   <table>
        <TR><TD ROWSPAN=8 >
          <div>
            <h3> <?php
                    echo Html::a( Html::encode($model->name, $model->pedigrees_id), Url::to(['pedigrees/view', 'id' => $model->pedigrees_id])); 
                    echo Html::img('/web/images/photo_p/'.$model->photo_path, [ 'class'=>'img-responsive img-rounded']);;
                    echo "</h3>";
                    echo "<ul>
                            <li>$model->color</li>
                            <li>$model->land_stand</li>
                            <li>$model->date_birth</li>
                            <li>$model->titles</li>                                    
                    </ul> </div> </div> </TD>";
                 ?>
                <?php if ($model->parentsir) {   
                          echo "   <TD ROWSPAN=4 >

                                <div class=header><h3>sir1_1 ";
                                    echo Html::a( Html::encode($model->parentsir->name, $model->parentsir->pedigrees_id), Url::to(['pedigrees/view', 'id' => $model->parentsir->pedigrees_id]));
                                    echo Html::img('/web/images/photo_p/'.$model->parentsir->photo_path, [ 'class'=>'img-responsive img-rounded']);
                                    echo "<br>";
                                    echo Html::label( $model->parentsir->color);
                                    echo Html::label( $model->parentsir->date_birth);
                                    echo Html::label( $model->parentsir->titles);

                            echo "</h3></div>
                    </TD>
                    <TD ROWSPAN=2 >
                       <div class=header><h3>sir1_3";
                           if ($model->parentsir->parentsir) {
                              echo Html::a( Html::encode($model->parentsir->parentsir->name, $model->parentsir->parentsir->pedigrees_id), Url::to(['pedigrees/view', 'id' => $model->parentsir->parentsir->pedigrees_id]));
                              echo Html::img('/web/images/'.$model->parentsir->parentsir->photo_path, ['class'=>'img-responsive img-rounded']);
                              echo Html::label( $model->parentsir->parentsir->color);
                              echo Html::label( $model->parentsir->parentsir->date_birth);
                              echo Html::label( $model->parentsir->parentsir->titles);
                          } else {
                              echo "no info";
                        }    
                        ETC...
</table>
```

i have lov skill for YII2 and php
may be some have better solution for this?
or can help with this example for this [solution for YII1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881221/pedigree-family-tree-chart-from-database) Remake for yii2?

Comment: First thing i can see is you need to modify your `getParentsir` method and instead of having `['pedigrees_id' => 'sire']` change it to `['pedigrees_id' => 'sire_id']`. Do the same for `getParentdam`.

Comment: thanks. yes. edited.

Comment: But in this methot i can get only 3 records of sir and dam. if i try get info record 4 i see no info, i mean <pre> <code> parentdam->parentdam->parentdam->parentdam-> "info"<code> but for full table i need 7 record of sir and 7 records of dam. for Exaple http://allpedigrees.info/?view=pedigree&dog_id=514&gens=4