# How to create a family tree (pedigree) with python from a database?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, select, recursive-query

I am wanting to create a reverse family tree (pedigree), that starts with the child and displays the entire line up until the first couple.
My database has 1000s of entries and has a schema and accompanying example like this:

```
0 id    |   17444
5 Sire  |   100
6 did   |   203
7 Dam   |   102
11 Name |   Bruce
```

Where the child is represented by Name and did. The entries Dam and Sire are also dids.

I've attempted something like the following:

```
def pedigree(did):
    con = sqlite3.connect('subjects.db')
    cursor = con.execute('SELECT * FROM animals where did IS "%s" ' % did)
    for row in cursor:
        print(row[11])
        pedigree(row[5])
        pedigree(row[7])
```

Which prints out a wall of text such as:

```
Bruce
Thomas
Martha
Partick
Sara
Kenneth
Catherine
```

I am thinking I should be using some sort of ADT, but I have not messed with those since college.
Any helpful advice would be great!
This is not a school assignment, it's something my wife wants, haha.

This question is nearly identical to my own, and they've gotten just as far: [Pedigree/Family tree chart from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881221/pedigree-family-tree-chart-from-database)

Answer (score 2):

An option would be to use a recursive common table expression to traverse the hierarchical structure:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select name, sire, dam, 0 lvl from animals where did = ?
    union all
    select a.name, a.sire, a.dam, c.lvl + 1
    from cte c
    inner join animals a on a.did in (c.sire, c.dam)
)
select * from cte order by lvl
```

The anchor of the recursive query selects the initial row by `did`; then, the recursive part follows the relationship upwards, selecting the records that correspond to the `sire` and `dam` of the previous iteration, until the tree exhausts. As a bonus, I added a column called `lvl` that represents the depth of each node in the tree.

Basically, this mimics the algorithm you implemented in your application code - however this should be much more efficient, since the whole work is performed at once in the database, rather than iterating in python and running multiple queries.