# MySQL Stored Procedure to generate Pedigree/Family tree chart

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to generate pedigree [in other words family tree :)] table with MySQL Stored procedure ....

My schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `horses` ( 
`horse_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`horse_name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`SireID` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`DamID` int(10) DEFAULT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`horse_id`),
KEY `FKsire` (`SireID`),
KEY `FKdam` (`DamID`),
CONSTRAINT `FKdam` FOREIGN KEY (`DamID`) REFERENCES `horses` (`horse_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FKsire` FOREIGN KEY (`SireID`) REFERENCES `horses` (`horse_id`)
)
```

p.s. 'SireID' and 'DamID' represents parents ID. I have spent days on this problem, searching, experimenting... And currently I do not have any working solution:

Can anyone help to generate table in one row :(. I want to build something like this reference https://www.pedigreequery.com/malibu2

Any help or hint is highly appreciated :), Thanks in advance

Comment: Specify precise MySQL version. Add sample data as textual INSERT INTO and desired output for this data as formatted plain table.

Comment: Hi Akina, I am using Version 5.0.2 , for samples you can check <https://www.pedigreequery.com/malibu2> page, I want to build the same thing but with MySQL and CodeIgniter

Comment: Hi Akina, Thanks for your help in advance, I just want to get the whole pedigree table in single database call and show it on page. Array with Horse ID, Horse Name, Horse Dam ID, Horse Dam Name, Horse Sire ID, Horse Sire Name. (Dam & Sire are parents) for each hierarchy

Comment: You have already asked this question today which was closed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69685786/pedigree-family-tree-chart-with-mysql-for-codeigniter

Comment: Hi shadow,Yes, but without any answer the question was closed, so I posted again to get any answer

Comment: You have not improved your question, so what diferent outcome do you expect?

Comment: Hi Shadow, can you help me in formatting this question properly, I have a Hoses Table in database and require an output for Horses Pedigree/Family tree. Sorry I am not good in Databases and English too ..

Comment: At the moment this does not read as a question, it reads as a specification for which you expect full code from scratch. You need to show what you have tried. You must also realise that mysql is a database, not a grsphical user interface. It cannot generate the output you linked on a html page.

Comment: Sorry, but I found this question --  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881221/pedigree-family-tree-chart-from-database?rq=1
so I tried it but was not successful, then I drafted my own question again similar to the above

Comment: Do not explain in words!!! "sample data as textual INSERT INTO and desired output for this data as formatted plain table" - why you cannot do these simple things precisely?

Comment: I am just asking for some help, I not good in Databases. If any body can help me with this  they are most welcome I have already spend days to figure out for answers but failed. 
Just need some help.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way you can do that in MySQL, but you can format the data into html tags then copy to a plain text, rename the plain text to "someName.html" then you can see it the way you want.

**Example**:

- 1 - Creating the table

```
    CREATE TABLE person(
    category varchar(100)
    ,age int
    ,fullName varchar(100));
```

- 2 - Populating the table

```
    INSERT INTO person
    VALUES('A', 20, 'Alexander')
    ,('A', 20, 'Mary')
    ,('A', 25, 'Roger')
    ,('A', 25, 'Penny')
    ,('B', 21, 'Rony')
    ,('B', 20, 'Karen')
    ,('B', 25, 'Peter');
```

- 3 - The query

```
    SELECT '<table><tr><th>Category</th><th>Age</th><th>Full Name</th></tr>'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT('<tr>'
                ,IF(prevCategory IS NULL,CONCAT('<td rowspan="',q_rows_category,'">',category,'</td>'),'')
                ,IF(prevAge IS NULL,CONCAT('<td rowspan="',q_rows_age,'">',age,'</td>'),'')
                ,CONCAT('<td>',fullName,'</td>')
                ,'</tr>') as html_body
      FROM (SELECT p.category,LAG(category,1) OVER(PARTITION BY p.category ORDER BY p.category,p.age) as prevCategory
                   ,LEAD(category,1) OVER(PARTITION BY p.category ORDER BY p.category,p.age) as nextCategory
                   ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM person t WHERE t.category = p.category) AS q_rows_category
                   ,p.age,LAG(age,1) OVER(PARTITION BY p.category,p.age ORDER BY p.category,p.age) as prevAge
                   ,LAG(age,1) OVER(PARTITION BY p.category,p.age ORDER BY p.category,p.age) as nextAge
                   ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM person t WHERE t.category = p.category AND t.age = p.age) AS q_rows_age
                   ,p.fullName
              FROM person p) a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '</table>';
```

- 4 - The result

```
    <table><tr><th>Category</th><th>Age</th><th>Full Name</th></tr>
    <tr><td rowspan="4">A</td><td rowspan="2">20</td><td>Alexander</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Mary</td></tr>
    <tr><td rowspan="2">25</td><td>Penny</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Roger</td></tr>
    <tr><td rowspan="3">B</td><td rowspan="1">20</td><td>Karen</td></tr>
    <tr><td rowspan="1">21</td><td>Rony</td></tr>
    <tr><td rowspan="1">25</td><td>Peter</td></tr>
    </table>
```

- 5 - HTML skeleton

```
   

     <html>
        <head>
            <style type="text/css">
                table {
                    width: 50%;
                }
                td, th {
                    border: 1px solid #000;
                    text-align: center;
                }
            </style>
         </head>
         <body>
            <center>

            PASTE THE DATA HERE!
            
            </center>
        </body>
     </html>
```

- 6 - See Results
  [image: example final data]